# Generate a random number in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I don't know why but I cant seem to see how random number generation works in LibGDX, no good examples of it being used that I can find either. Just wondering how you can just random a number 1-3 then System.out it. Bonus - How can you random a new number every second?

Comment: The utility class com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer contains a #schedule method to plan repeated actions outside of the render cycle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use standard Java to do that.

```
Random random = new Random();
int oneTwoThree = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

This will generate a random int (0, 1 or 2) and then add 1, resulting in 1, 2 or 3.

If you want to switch it every second, then you need to keep track of the time in your `render(float)` method

```
private float countDown;

private int randomNumber;

public void render(float deltaTime) {
    countDown -= deltaTime;
    if (countDown <= 0) {
        Random random = new Random();
        randomNumber= random.nextInt(3) + 1;
        countDown += 1000; // add one second
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Where do I throw in the timer chunk of code? Still trying to grasp the concept of the render things >.>

Comment: It goes in your render method, like in this code snipped. You should read this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle

Comment: If I put it inside my render() It doesnt seem to do anything. The render() is not the same as the render(float deltaTime) correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to put it in render(float). That's the method that LibGDX will call. If you have a render() method (no parameter), then this will not be called automatically.

Comment: Yeah I have a render() with no parameters with movement controls etc in it, how can I have both of them? Sorry for all the questions =P

Comment: Avoid creating garbage, use `MathUtils.random(...);` See http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html

Comment: Yeah i've seen those but I have 0 idea on how to actually get them to work, any chance you could give me a quick example on how to use one of them?

Comment: You should take a look at getting started with libgdx if you have such questions. Or take a look at this for an better understanding: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

Comment: Thanks. It feels like the tut i was following really rushes through a lot of important things

Answer (score 2):

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;


int random = MathUtils.random.nextInt(4);

        if(random == 0){

        }else if (random == 1){

        }else if (random == 2){

        }else{

        }
```